# How to determine which configuration is read at run time

Tags: asp.net

I have several configuration entries for application.
Identical entries are stored in Machine.config/Web.config etc..
How would I determine which one is read at run time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Configuration API to open machine configuration.

ContextInformation.IsMachineLevel is what you need.
Configuration.EvaluationContext gives you the ContextInformation object and ElementInformation object gives you all the information including down to the source file path and the line number.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection_properties.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.contextinformation.ismachinelevel.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.elementinformation_members.aspx

You can use OpenMachineConfiguration method to open particular configuration files.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228063.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In general, `Web.config` settings in a folder inherits and can override settings from the `Web.config` files in parent folders, the application root `Web.config` file, and the `machine.config` file.

Consequently, settings in the closest `Web.config` file take precedence over the root `Web.config` file and the `machine.config` file. There's a catch though. You can't define all settings in all places. Some settings can only get defined at `machine.config` level. Some can be defined at the application root level but not in subfolders.

Comment: Question is How to determine which one of them(Machine.config/Web.config) is read at run time

Comment: From his answer, it seems that the most deeply nested web.config > less nested web.config > machine.config.